# PHP print tabs from database

Tags: php, tabs

There's a simple way to include 
 when there's a new line in the database (nl2br), but is there anything similar for tabs?

I've tried different solutions which works in the way of the look, but not when you're copying the code. I've tried a CSS style and made it like:

```
#br{
margin-right: 30px;
float: left;
}
```

But once I copy the code, there's no tab. In my database there's a TAB, but how do I print the tab?

Comment: You could simply use css `white-space:pre;` on the element.

Comment: tabs have no meaning in html. they're just a single whitespace char, for all intents and purposes. if you want to include tabs, you'd need to convert them to a `<span>` or something with fixed-width, and even then you wouldn't get real "tab" behavior.

Comment: How come that some website allows me to copy code and it includes tabs?

Comment: In the ASCII, a tab (\t) can be copied. It can be stored in a database. It can be presented in HTML, yet it is not rendered as anything when the browser reads the HTML. With PHP you can identify the TAB in the text and convert it to something that can be rendered in HTML.

Comment: @Twisty That is not true. Space, tab an line breaks are all seen as white space. A sequence of one or more of these white space characters by default is rendered as a single space, although you can influence this using CSS or the `<pre>` tag. But even without that, tabs would still be rendered as spaces, not as 'nothing'.

Comment: @GolezTrol, I don't know if I agree. This is not to say what you posted is incorrect. Simply that the browser does not render Space, Tab, Carriage Return, or New Line as anything more than White Space unless the `PRE` tag is used to render all the preformated text. The character still exist in the source code.

Comment: I know. I'm just saying that rendering a space is something else than rendering nothing at all. The space itself isn't visible, but it influence the flow. 'Rendering nothing' suggests that tabs would look like zero-width characters, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a bit of CSS to display tabs as tabs.

```
#br {
   white-space: pre-wrap;
   tab-size: 4;
}
```

`pre-wrap` is the best solution, I think, because it still allows the text to wrap normally when a line is full. `pre` is also possible, but then the text won't break at the end of a line.

`tab-size` is optional. By default it is set to 8 spaces, but you can change that by specifying a number of spaces in this property.

Note that I've copied your CSS selector, `#br`, but normally I would make a class for this, so you can easily apply this style to any number of elements in your page.

Also note, since `pre-wrap` also displays line breaks as actual breaks, you probably won't need to call `nl2br` on the server anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can write  a function like `nl2br()`. Something like:

```
<?php
function tab2span($str){
    if(strpos($str, "\t"){
        $str = str_replace('\t','<span class="tabbed">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>',$str);
    }
    return $str;
}
?>
```

Then you can also adjust your CSS to style it better if you need.

Comment: is it required to have it in a function?

Comment: Nope. If you're reading a number of rows, you can just read direct from the `$row[]` and use `str_replace()` at that time. If you're doing it a lot, it just makes it a bit easier to call `$text = tab2span($row['text']);` in my opinion.